# Detach a method

Tags: scala

Is it possible to detach a method from a class?

```
class A {
  def b(C): D
}
```

Is there a function that takes `b` and returns a function with the
signature `A => C => D` or `(A,C) => D`?

Answer (score 2):

It's often not necessary to explicitly create a new binary function from a method with a single argument, because when the compiler expects such a function type, you can instead use the `_ methodName _` infix operator syntax for anonymous functions.

The first `_` takes the place of the target object (instance of A), and the second `_` takes the place of the argument to the method.

For example, if you had a potential use site

```
def swizzle(f: (A, C) => D) = sys.error("todo")
```

Then you could refer to the method `b` like this:

```
swizzle(_ b _)
```

Comment: Can I abstract the pattern `_ fun _` to a function that takes `fun` and returns `_ fun _`?

Comment: @Tass, how would you refer to fun? There isn't a type expressing a member of A, so I don't think you'd even be able to construct the argument `fun` you're hoping to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know about a function to do this, but it is easy to create such a function:

`val f: A => C => D = a => c => a b c`

Comment: And where is the function that takes `b` as argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can lift a method into a function by substituting an underscore for the parameter group of the method creating a partially applied function.

This requires a non-abstract method, so amending your example a little:

```
case class C()
case class D()

class A {
  def b(c: C): D = {
    val d: D = D()
    println("A.b("+c+") = "+d)
    d
  }
}
```

So the function would be

```
val afunc: A => C => D = (a: A) => a.b _
```

invoking the function with some example arguments ...

```
afunc(new A)(C())
```

outputs

```
A.b(C()) = D()
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called *eta expansion*. Here is the relevant part of the Scala Language Specification:

---

### 6.26.2 Method Conversions

The following four implicit conversions can be applied to methods which are not
applied to some argument list.

- **Evaluation**. A parameterless method `m` of type `=> T` is always converted to type
  `T` by evaluating the expression to which `m` is bound.
- **Implicit Application**. If the method takes only implicit parameters, implicit arguments are passed following the rules of §7.2.
- **Eta Expansion**. Otherwise, if the method is not a constructor, and the expected
  type pt is a function type `(Ts ) ⇒ T` , eta-expansion (§6.26.5) is performed on the
  expression `e`.
- **Empty Application**. Otherwise, if `e` has method type `()T` , it is implicitly applied to
  the empty argument list, yielding `e()`.

Comment: [Scala Language Specification](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf&ei=UDuvUNzyNaXj4QTY7oBI&usg=AFQjCNHwxfm9PxRh99_Ld9rj6oJnBboKQg)