# Simple syntax for treating a instance method as a function

Tags: scala, easybind

In Java, we can do something like this:

```
ObservableStringValue str = ...;
Binding<Integer> strLen = EasyBind.map(str, String::length);
```

Where `String::length` effectively is an instance method being used as a function. Is there an equivalent form in Scala? (And by extension, an equivalent way to use EasyBind in Scala)

Comment: Also relevant: [Detach a method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13473363/2988), [Difference between method and function in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2529184/2988), and [Scala: Referencing functions on object instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18899595/2988), among many many others.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> "dsfs".toString _
res1: () => String = <function0>
```